# HAML table row class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'd like to add a class to the table row like so:

```
  %tbody
    - @article.each do |x|
     %tr [add class here]
       %td= check_box_tag "check-box"
       %td= x.short_title
       %td= x.label.nil? ? '' : x.label.title
       %td= published_at(x)
       %td= last_update(x)
```

however when I try to I get the error:

Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %tr and nested within it.

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this:

```
%tbody
  - @article.each do |x|
     %tr.add-class-here
       %td= check_box_tag "check-box"
       %td= x.short_title
       %td= x.label.nil? ? '' : x.label.title
       %td= published_at(x)
       %td= last_update(x)
```

Comment: @soupdog problem is with Illegal nesting so the problem lies with in it..!

Comment: But your code looks identical to the code the OP posted, so how are you fixing the error? The illegal nesting looks to be because you are providing the string "[add class here]", which the interpreter is taking to be content. The syntax for adding a class to an element is `%element.class-name`

Comment: @soupdog no offense,  I agree with you on that but what I see it at first as a nesting error because OP was adding the class and he got that error

Comment: I see you updated your answer, so now your solution will in fact fix the problem, but your original answer was simply a copy/paste of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
  %tbody
    - @article.each do |x|
     %tr.some-class
       %td= check_box_tag "check-box"
       %td= x.short_title
       %td= x.label.nil? ? '' : x.label.title
       %td= published_at(x)
       %td= last_update(x)
```